# ArcGIS Parcel Fabric: Reset adjustments/transformations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, parcel, parcel-fabric

So I'm learning how to use parcel fabrics, and getting frustrated so far. I attempted to do an adjustment on one of my subdivision plans (600 parcels). I thought it worked, so I saved it. Then on closer inspection, I realized that ArcGIS had totally mangled my parcels. However, since I saved it, UNDO is no longer an option. Is there a way to reset the geometry for a parcel/plan/fabric back to the internal (COGO) geometry so I can start again?

It appears that the only help I can find from Esri on this is to delete the parcels and enter them again, but this seems like an idiotic "solution" (especially for 600 parcels). I have tried unjoining and rejoining them, but this keeps the warped geometries. I may be remembering things wrong, but it seems like the old survey analyst handled things like this much better.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Regenerate Fabric](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00wp0000004z000000) tool, which is not on the Parcel Fabric toolbar by default. You'll have to add it through the Customize menu. In theory this should regenerate your parcels based on the survey geometry attributes - I personally haven't had cause to try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that's not it. The Regenerate Fabric tool only rebuilds the parcel (polygon) geometry based on the (adjusted) points and lines. So nothing actually moves. Honestly, I'm not sure what this would be used for--maybe if you accidentally moved a parcel using the regular editing tools.